# RxJava :concat the whole bytes arrays into one array

Tags: java, arrays, rx-java

Is there any way to concat the whole bytes arrays listed in List to one array byte[] using operators in RxJava version 1.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No. Use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to collect up individual byte arrays and then get the whole array.

Comment: @akarnokd please could you give an example for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to collect up individual byte arrays and then get the whole array.

```java
List<byte[]> bytesList = ...

Observable.fromIterable(bytesList)
.collect(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, (bout, bytes) -> bout.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length))
.map(bout -> bout.toByteArray())
// work with the byte array
;
```

Comment: thanks for your help.I have a question if java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[] b, int off, int len) overwrite previous values